# How to Change/Set the download default location of webview in c#

Tags: c#, windows, webview

I have designed windows form application, in which i have implemented Webview.
In that i am navigating to different Url using webview.Navigate.
After navigating , i am downloading file from that url.
And file is downloading successfully, but it is downloading in default location i.e. **C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads.**

I want to change the default download location of webview.
Can we change the default download location of webview.
Or is there any other way to download at different location from webview.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

**It's a piece of cake ;)** Just change the [DefaultDownloadFolderPath Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2profile.defaultdownloadfolderpath?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) in your **webView2.CoreWebView2.Profile** once your WebView2 object has completed initialization. You can do it in the it's event handler:

```
webView2.CoreWebView2.Profile.DefaultDownloadFolderPath = "C:\\Your Downlaod Folder";
```

Note you have to  subscribe to the **CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted**  event either by double clicking it's field in the events tab of your **WebView2 object** properties window (F4 keyboard shortcut) or just do it in your Form's constructor:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += webView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;                
    }

private void webView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.Profile.DefaultDownloadFolderPath = "C:\\Your Downlaod Folder";
    }
```

Comment: This should be the top voted answer, imo.

Comment: Thnaks. That's kind of you

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using below or higher version of nuget *WebView2* package for your application:

*Install-Package Microsoft.Web.WebView2 -Version 1.0.865-prerelease*

in order to manage download progress you may try code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BirWV.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
        await InitializeAsync(BirWV);
        BirWV.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https//myurl.com");
    }
    private void CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting(object sender, CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        downloadOperation = e.DownloadOperation; 
        e.ResultFilePath = @"C:\mytargetdowloadpath\mydownloadedfile.zip";
    }
    public async Task InitializeAsync(WebView2 wv, string webCacheDir = "")
    {
        CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = null;
        string tempWebCacheDir = string.Empty;
        CoreWebView2Environment webView2Environment = null;
        tempWebCacheDir = webCacheDir;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempWebCacheDir))
        {
            tempWebCacheDir = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            tempWebCacheDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(tempWebCacheDir, System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
        }
        webView2Environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, tempWebCacheDir, options);
        await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
        var initTaskField = BirWV.GetType().GetField("_initTask", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        dynamic initTask = initTaskField.GetValue(wv);
        BirWV.CoreWebView2.DownloadStarting += CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting;
    }
    private void WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Please check *WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted* method is being reached after running in debug mode.